# Chmods don't seem to apply

Tags: linux, debian, chmod

I have a script I periodically run that reapplies FACL and chmod permissions for home directories of gameservers I run.

The script first issues a home-directory wide recursive chmod, and then chmods certain files to specific values (first all files are set to 770, then additional changes are made).

Relevant bit from the script:

```
for d in */; do
    < server verification and type checking >
    chmod -R 770 ${d%/}
    chmod 771 ${d%/}
    chmod 775 ${d%/}/$gamedir
    < ... chmodding unrelated game asset directories for webserver access ... >
    for k in "${BLOCK_DIRS[@]}"; do
        if [ -d "$k" ]; then
            echo -e "${CYAN}Checking $(pwd)/$k...${NC}"
            echo -e "${RED}Debug: chmod -R 1700 $(pwd)/$k${NC}"
            chmod -v 1700 "$(pwd)/$k"
            chmod -R 0700 "$(pwd)/$k"
        fi
    done
done
```

Sample output:

```
mode of ‘/home/servers/tf_test/tf/../bin’ changed from 0770 (rwxrwx---) to 1700 (rwx-----T)
```

However, directory permissions only change for the last server in the first loop. That is, there are 9 servers in the first for loop, and only the last one gets changes by the inner for loop.

Same commands issued manually work absolutely fine.
What am I doing wrong?

(also, this is my first question - if I didn't say something important - please correct me, I'll edit the question accordingly)

Comment: Welcome to the site. What are `BLOCK_DIRS`?

Comment: BLOCK_DIRS are the directories that are supposed to be protected, and it's an array - I have however responded to the question - it's no longer active. Huge thanks for trying to help, though!

Comment: As a side note, do all these files really need execute permissions, that is, are they executable files? If not, you should apply 600 permissions to them.

Answer (score 1):

`ls` doesn't show access flags for the owner group - it shows the highest group's access, and that fooled me. I also rearranged the chmods in the script so they first chmod the directory's contents and then the directory itself, and the sticky bit now works.
As for the `ls` group permissions issue.

```
foo@bar:/foo# ls -lha game_server | grep bin
drwxrwx--T+  2 gameaccount  gameaccount  4.0K Dec 21 20:56 bin
foo@bar:/foo#
```

The directory is owned by gameaccount, and it looks like the group gameaccount that owns it has the 7 permission bit, right? **Wrong**

```
foo@bar:/foo# getfacl game_server/bin
# file: game_server/bin
# owner: gameaccount
# group: gameaccount
# flags: --t
user::rwx
group::---
group:root:rwx
mask::rwx
other::---
```

Question can be closed - ls just didn't show the permission bits I expected.

Comment: Hi quake84, just accept your answer to "close" the question

Comment: It says I can accept it in 2 days.